# Stop audio when is playing another one in Unity3D

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

How can I stop one audio when is playing another one?

```
public AudioSource audioSource;
public AudioClip audioClip;
private string[,] levelWords;
//public static string glupiaZmienna;
public Text txt;

public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log(gameObject.name);
    WordsLoader w = new WordsLoader();
    levelWords = w.wLevelWords;
    SetCategoryButton scb = new SetCategoryButton();
    int a = scb.Kategoria;
    zupa();

    AudioSource audio = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    audio.Stop();
    audio.clip = (AudioClip)Resources.Load(a+ "/" + WordsLoader.language + "/Sounds/" + gameObject.name);

    audio.Play();


   // txt = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
}

public void zupa()
{ WordsLoader w = new WordsLoader();
    SetCategoryButton scb = new SetCategoryButton();
    int a = scb.Kategoria;
    print(w.wHowManyWords);

    for (int i = 0; i < w.wHowManyWords; i++)
    {
        print("jestem tu");
        if (levelWords[i, 0] == gameObject.name)
        {
            txt = GameObject.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>(); ;
            txt.text = levelWords[i, 2];
        }

    }
}
```

This code is in a script which start playing a sound after click a button. I would like stop earlier started audio.

Comment: Please explain your problem more. This one line question is not answerable. Which audio to stop and which one to play?

Comment: Is this piece of code running on the-same GameObject each time or different GameObject?

Comment: It is the same game object

Comment: it's created every time when user clicks on a button

Comment: I am sorry, I don't want add a useless answer. You should also post code that is calling that. Put them in a function like it is on your side.

Comment: There is all code now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: *Answer has to change a-lot due to comments left under it. It makes sense to overwrite everything.*

You need a reference that points to all the `AudioSource`. Store every `ClickAction` instance in a `List`, in another script(`PlayerManager`). Before you play the audio, loop through that `List` and stop playing it if it is playing. After that, you can then play your audio.

Also, you currently call `Resources.Load` each time you want to play the Audio. This is not good in terms of performance. You should do this once in the `Start()` function, then play it when it is needed. Also, your `gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>()` code should only be called once too.

Your new `ClickAction` script:

```
public class ClickAction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip audioClip;
    private string[,] levelWords;
    //public static string glupiaZmienna;
    public Text txt;

    public AudioSource clickAudioSource;
    PlayerManager playerManager = null;

    void Start()
    {
        //Get PlayerManager from PlayerManager GameObject
        playerManager = GameObject.Find("PlayerManager").GetComponent<PlayerManager>();
        clickAudioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        clickAudioSource.clip = (AudioClip)Resources.Load(a + "/" + WordsLoader.language + "/Sounds/" + gameObject.name);

        //Register this Script to the PlayerManager 
        playerManager.addClickAction(this);
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name);
        WordsLoader w = new WordsLoader();
        levelWords = w.wLevelWords;
        SetCategoryButton scb = new SetCategoryButton();
        int a = scb.Kategoria;
        zupa();

        //Play Audio
        playAudio();

        // txt = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    private void playAudio()
    {
        playerManager.playAudio(clickAudioSource);
    }

    public void stopAudio()
    {
        //If not null and playing then stop audio
        if (clickAudioSource != null && clickAudioSource.isPlaying)
        {
            clickAudioSource.Stop();
        }
    }

    public void zupa()
    {
        WordsLoader w = new WordsLoader();
        SetCategoryButton scb = new SetCategoryButton();
        int a = scb.Kategoria;
        print(w.wHowManyWords);

        for (int i = 0; i < w.wHowManyWords; i++)
        {
            print("jestem tu");
            if (levelWords[i, 0] == gameObject.name)
            {
                txt = GameObject.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>(); ;
                txt.text = levelWords[i, 2];
            }

        }
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        //Un-Register this Script from the PlayerManager when it is destroyed
        playerManager.removeClickAction(this);
    }
}
```

`PlayerManager` script. Create a GameObject called `PlayerManager`, then attach the script below to it:

```
public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<ClickAction> clickActions = new List<ClickAction>();

    public void addClickAction(ClickAction clickActionToAdd)
    {
        //Adds clickActionToAdd if it does not exist in the List already
        if (!clickActions.Contains(clickActionToAdd))
        {
            clickActions.Add(clickActionToAdd);
        }
    }

    public void removeClickAction(ClickAction clickActionToAdd)
    {
        //Removes clickActionToAdd if it exist in the List 
        if (clickActions.Contains(clickActionToAdd))
        {
            clickActions.Add(clickActionToAdd);
        }
    }

    public bool clickActionExist(ClickAction clickActionToAdd)
    {
        //Removes clickActionToAdd if it exist in the List 
        return clickActions.Contains(clickActionToAdd);
    }

    public void playAudio(AudioSource audSource)
    {
        //Stop Other Audio
        stopAllClickActionAudio();

        //Now, play the one that was passed in
        audSource.Play();
    }

    void stopAllClickActionAudio()
    {
        //Stop Audio on every ClickAction script
        for (int i = 0; i < clickActions.Count; i++)
        {
            clickActions[i].stopAudio();
        }
    }
}
```

When the `playAudio` function is called, it will stop all audio from `AudioSource` that is stored in the `List`, then it will play the current `AudioSource` that is passed into it.

Comment: That still doesn't work. Could it be because I have the same script added to some objects?

Comment: Asked you you about this in the comment section and you said "Is this piece of code running on the-same GameObject each time or different GameObject?." Now, you are saying that the script is attached to different GameObjects.

Comment: I understood your question from another way. I'm sorry

Comment: TBH I really don't understand what you are doing to begin with. The code in your question does not look ok. Can you explain what you are doing? How many buttons? What are your goals with that code?

Comment: I create 10 objects (people). This script is added to every object. When I click to one of them -this person can "say her/his name"(audio). I don't want a situation when everybody is speaking in the same time

Comment: This makes sense and too many things needs to be changed in the code. I am working on but I have two questions. What is the name of this script that contains the code? Are those 10 GameObjects instantiated during run-time or do they exist already before Play button is pressed?

Comment: Name of this script is "ClickAction". Those objects are instantiated during run-time because I wanted dinamically create levels

Comment: Check the Edit. Many things changed. The way you do this right now is not ok.